# ¿Cómo ordenar categorías de blog según el número de visitas en artículos con MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo tres tablas:

**categories** - categorías

```
|------|------------|
|  id  |   nombre   |
|------|------------|
|  1   | categoria1 |
|  2   | categoria2 |
|  3   | categoria3 |
|------|------------|
```

**items** - artículos de blog

```
|------|-----------------|----------------|
|  id  |   category_id   |   item_title   |
|------|-----------------|----------------|
|   1  |       2         |   lo q sea..   |
|   2  |       1         |   lo q sea..   |
|   3  |       3         |   lo q sea..   |
|   4  |       2         |   lo q sea..   |
|------|-----------------|----------------|
```

**views_unique** - visitas únicas para articulos de blog

```
|----|-----------|
| id |  item_id  |
|----|-----------|
| 1  |     2     |
| 2  |     3     |
| 3  |     3     |
| 4  |     1     |
| 5  |     1     |
| 6  |     2     |
| 7  |     1     |
|----|-----------|
```

**Resultado deseado**
Quiero obtener una tabla como esta:

```
|--------------------------|-----------------------|---------------------|
|   nombre_de_categorias   |   cantidad_de_items   |       visitas       |
|--------------------------|-----------------------|---------------------|
|  categoria1              |         1             |         3           |
|  categoria2              |         2             |         2           |
|  categoria3              |         1             |         2           |
|--------------------------|-----------------------|---------------------|
```

He intentado de todo. Mi ultimo intento:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items i
    WHERE c.id = i.category_id) AS cantidad_de_items,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM views_unique vu
    WHERE i.category_id = c.id ) AS visitas
    FROM categories c
    ORDER BY visitas DESC;
```

La cantidad de items me da bien, pero visitas: no.

Comment: Ascendente o descendente?

Comment: @AlfredoPaz DESC :D aunque casi da igual .. Gracias por tu comentario!

Comment: en la parte final de tu código donde dice order by name, debería ser order by visitas desc;

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, pero no resuelve el problema :/

Comment: El planteamiento no es claro y creo que los resultados que esperas no son reales. ¿Por qué, para poner un ejemplo, en la fila uno de los resultados deseados esperas `1` para `cantidad_de_items` y `3` para `visitas`?  ¿a qué correspondería el `1` en ese caso?

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano por tu comentario. He editado un porquito la preguta. El `1` es la cantidad de articulos del blog que están en la `categoría1` mientras `3` es la cantidad de usuarios que visitaron un articulo del blog en `categoria1`. A ver si ha quedado un poquito mas claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar `JOIN`, `COUNT` y `SUM` para relacionar los datos a`GROUP`ados.

Separo las diferentes partes asi se nota como se arma:

Para saber los nombres de las categorias

```
SELECT id as category_id, nombre as nombre_de_categorias FROM categories WHERE 1;
```

Para saber cuantos items tiene cada categoria

```
SELECT category_id, COUNT(category_id) as cantidad_de_items
  FROM items
  GROUP BY category_id;
```

Para saber cuantas visitas tiene cada item

```
SELECT item_id, COUNT(item_id) as visitas_por_item
  FROM views_unique
  GROUP BY item_id;
```

Joineamos y sumamos para saber cuantas visitas por categoria

```
SELECT i.category_id, 
       COUNT(i.category_id) as cantidad_de_items, 
       SUM(vu.visitas_por_item) as visitas
  FROM items i
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT item_id, COUNT(item_id) as visitas_por_item
  FROM views_unique
  GROUP BY item_id) vu ON vu.item_id = i.id
  GROUP BY i.category_id;
```

Joineamos los resultados para tener los nombres de la categorias, ordenamos por visitas

```
SELECT i.category_id,
       c.nombre as nombre_de_categorias,
       COUNT(i.category_id) as cantidad_de_items,
       SUM(vu.visitas_por_item) as visitas
  FROM items i
  LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.id = i.category_id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT item_id, COUNT(item_id) as visitas_por_item
  FROM views_unique
  GROUP BY item_id) vu ON vu.item_id = i.id
  GROUP BY i.category_id
  ORDER BY visitas DESC;
```

Un fiddel http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/730c6c/3

Comment: Brillante! Gracias!